# Shopware 6: Access theme sass varaiables in administration sass / cms element

Tags: shopware6

How can i access storefront sass variables like `$sw-color-brand-primary` in administration sass files?

I have a custom cms element and want to style the preview in the designer with the defined theme colors:

***my-plugin/src/Resources/app/administration/src/modules/sw-cms/elements/my-image/component/my-image-el.scss***

```
.my-class{
  color: $sw-color-brand-primary;
}
```

=> SassError: Undefined variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme variables/colors aren't available in the administration. They may vary from sales channel to sales channel, so there is possibly not just the one primary color across all sales channel. That would make the preview inaccurate anyway.

For that reason Shopware's own elements also use replacement colors in the preview. For example the buy button in the preview of the product detail page layout uses `$color-darkgray-200`, which is not the same as the primary color of the default template. So the preview in the administration is not meant to be an exact representation of the storefront view.

If you want to stay close to the look and feel of the administration use  the administration's own variables.

```scss
@import "~scss/variables";

.my-class {
  color: $color-darkgray-200;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. That was also my approach so far. Then I'll continue to solve it that way.